# If $z_1,\dotsc,z_n$ are the vertices of a regular $n$-gon, with $z_3 + z_n = Az_1 + \bar{A}z_2$, find $\lfloor |A| \rfloor$.

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, polygons

The question goes:

> The complex numbers $z_1, z_2, z_3 \ldots z_n, \sum_{i=1}^{n} z_i \neq 0$ represent the vertices of a regular polygon of $n$ sides in order, inscribed in a circle of unit radius such that $z_3 + z_n =A\cdot z_1 + \bar A\cdot z_2$ Find $\lfloor |A|\rfloor$ when $n=4,6,8,12$.

In my attempt I tried to generalize over $n$. My attempt:

Suppose $z_1=e^{i\phi}$. Now, $$z_j=e^{i((j-1)\frac{2\pi}{n} + \phi)}$$

On substitution, I obtained
$$e^{i\frac{4\pi}{n}}+e^{i(n-1)\frac{2\pi}{n}}=A+\bar A\cdot e^{i\frac{2\pi}{n}}=A+i\bar A $$

Then I put $A=x +iy$ and $n=4$ to end up with $-1-i=(x+y)+i(x+y)$ giving me only $x+y=-1$.

If I'm going right, how should I proceed? Thanks in advance.

Edit:
The answers are $2,2,1,1$ respectively.

Edit 2: The original question. [image]
Answer is A-R,B-R,C-Q,D-Q.

Edit 3: The solution as given by the problem setter.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Assuming $|A|$ denotes the complex modulus, it seems to me that $A$ should just be $e^{i 4 \pi / n}$ (and hence $|A| = 1$ always. You can observe that $z_3 = A z_1$, and $z_n = \bar A z_2.$ Although from the work you've shown it doesn't seem to be the unique solution in the $n = 4$ case (or maybe I'm missing something).

Comment: @paulinho Yes it does mean complex modulus.

Comment: Are you sure the answers are correct? Is the problem copied correctly? Because our answers agree.

Comment: @paulinho Yes. I'm positive. That's probably not a great choice of words but yes, I've copied it correctly. P.S. sorry for the sorry attempt at sarcasm.

Comment: Well, originally the question was of match the column type and I tweaked it just a bit. If you want I can attach the original question as well.

Comment: Feel free to do so.

Comment: I reformulated the equation as follows. Let $c=\frac 1m\sum z_j$ be the center of the polygon.  Let $\xi=e^{\pm 2\pi/n}$, where the sign depends on the orientation of the order of the vertices $z_j$ along the boundary of the polygon. Then $z_j=c+(z_1-c)\xi^{j-1}$ for  each $1\le j\le n$. Put $w=z_1-c$. Let $|A|=a$ and $A=a\psi$. Then $\bar A=a\psi^{-1}$ amd $|\xi|=|w|=|\psi|=1$. We have $c+w\xi^2+ c+w\xi^{-1}=a\psi(c+w)+a\psi^{-1}(c+w\xi)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n \geq 4$. We are given that $z_1, \dotsc, z_n$ are the vertices of a regular $n$-gon inscribed in a circle in the complex plane, with $\sum_i z_i \neq 0$. So, letting $w := x_0 + iy_0$ denote the centre of the circle, we have $w \neq 0$.

Let $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ such that $z_1 = w + e^{i \theta}$. Then, $$z_j = w + e^{i(\theta + 2\pi(j-1)/n)} = \left[x_0 + \cos\left(\theta + \frac{2\pi(j-1)}{n}\right)\right] + i\left[y_0 + \sin\left(\theta + \frac{2\pi(j-1)}{n}\right)\right]$$ for all $j = 1, \dotsc, n$.
Hence,
$$
z_3 + z_n = \left[2x_0 + \cos\left(\theta + \frac{4\pi}{n}\right) + \cos\left(\theta + \frac{2(n-1)\pi}{n}\right)\right] + i\left[2y_0 + \sin\left(\theta + \frac{4\pi}{n}\right)+\sin\left(\theta + \frac{2(n-1)\pi}{n}\right)\right].
$$
Let $A = p + iq$. Then,
$$
Az_1 + \bar{A}z_2 = \left\{\left[ 2x_0 + \cos( \theta ) + \cos\left( \theta + \frac{2\pi}{n} \right)\right]p + \left[-\sin( \theta ) + \sin\left( \theta + \frac{2\pi}{n} \right) \right]q \right\} + i \left\{\left[ 2y_0 + \sin( \theta ) + \sin\left( \theta + \frac{2\pi}{n} \right)\right]p + \left[\cos( \theta ) - \cos\left( \theta + \frac{2\pi}{n} \right) \right]q\right\}.
$$
We are given that $z_3 + z_n = Az_1 + \bar{A}z_2$. So, equating the real and imaginary parts of the two sides, we get a system of two linear equations in two unknowns:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2x_0 + \cos( \theta ) + \cos\left( \theta + \frac{2\pi}{n} \right) & -\sin( \theta ) + \sin\left( \theta + \frac{2\pi}{n} \right)\\
2y_0 + \sin( \theta ) + \sin\left( \theta + \frac{2\pi}{n} \right) & \cos( \theta ) - \cos\left( \theta + \frac{2\pi}{n} \right)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
p \\
q
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
2x_0 + \cos\left(\theta + \frac{4\pi}{n}\right) + \cos\left(\theta + \frac{2(n-1)\pi}{n}\right) \\
2y_0 + \sin\left(\theta + \frac{4\pi}{n}\right)+\sin\left(\theta + \frac{2(n-1)\pi}{n}\right)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now, the determinant of the matrix of coefficients is
$$
\Delta = 4 \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{n} \right) \left[ -y_0 \cos\left( \theta + \frac{\pi}{n} \right) + x_0 \cos\left( \theta + \frac{\pi}{n} \right) \right],
$$
so $\Delta = 0 \iff w$ lies on the line with slope $\tan\left(\theta + \frac{\pi}{n} \right)$. Note: here we mean that $w$ lies on the imaginary axis if $\theta + \pi/n = \pi/2$ or $3\pi/2$.

Suppose that $\Delta \neq 0$. Then, left multiplying by the inverse of the matrix of coefficients, we get
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
p\\
q
\end{bmatrix}
=
\frac{1}{\Delta}
\begin{bmatrix}
2x_0\left[ \cos( \theta ) - \cos\left( \theta + \frac{2\pi}{n} \right) \right] + 2y_0\left[ \sin(\theta) - \sin\left( \theta + \frac{2\pi}{n} \right) \right] \\
\\
2x_0\left[ - \sin(\theta) - \sin\left( \theta + \frac{2\pi}{n} \right) + \sin\left( \theta + \frac{4\pi}{n} \right) + \sin\left( \theta + \frac{2(n-1)\pi}{n} \right)\right] + 2y_0\left[ \cos(\theta) + \cos\left( \theta + \frac{2\pi}{n} \right) -\cos\left( \theta + \frac{4\pi}{n} \right) - \cos\left( \theta + \frac{2(n-1)\pi}{n} \right)\right]
\end{bmatrix}
=
\frac{1}{\Delta}
\begin{bmatrix}
\Delta\\
-2\Delta\sin\left( \frac{2\pi}{n} \right)
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Hence, $$A = 1 - 2i\sin\left( \frac{2\pi}{n} \right).$$
Since $\sin(\pi - x) = \sin(x)$ for all $x$, and $\pi - 2\pi/n$ is the interior angle of the polygon, our solution for $A$ matches the one in the "official" solution.

---

Now, the given solution is damn clever and makes my calculations look caveman-like. But, just so I can salvage some of my previous attempt, I will note that the "official" solution actually does not make use of the fact that $\sum_i z_i \neq 0$ anywhere! This suggests that they are implicitly dealing with the non-degenerate case only.
Since we've come so far, let's complete the degenerate case as well. :)

Firstly, our analysis tells us that the *correct* criterion for degeneracy is $\Delta = 0$. This is the condition that $w$ lies on the line with slope $\tan\left( \theta + \frac{\pi}{n} \right)$. This is stronger than the given condition, which just says that $w$ must not be the origin.

So, let's assume that $\Delta = 0$. In this case, the system of linear equations looks like:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\pm 2\lvert w \rvert \cos\left( \theta + \frac{\pi}{n} \right) + \cos( \theta ) + \cos\left( \theta + \frac{2\pi}{n} \right) & -\sin( \theta ) + \sin\left( \theta + \frac{2\pi}{n} \right)\\
\pm 2\lvert w \rvert \sin\left( \theta + \frac{\pi}{n} \right) + \sin( \theta ) + \sin\left( \theta + \frac{2\pi}{n} \right) & \cos( \theta ) - \cos\left( \theta + \frac{2\pi}{n} \right)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
p \\
q
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\pm 2\lvert w \rvert \cos\left( \theta + \frac{\pi}{n} \right) + \cos\left(\theta + \frac{4\pi}{n}\right) + \cos\left(\theta + \frac{2(n-1)\pi}{n}\right) \\
\pm 2\lvert w \rvert \sin\left( \theta + \frac{\pi}{n} \right) + \sin\left(\theta + \frac{4\pi}{n}\right)+\sin\left(\theta + \frac{2(n-1)\pi}{n}\right)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which can be simplified to
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 \cos\left( \theta + \frac{\pi}{n} \right) \left[ \pm \lvert w \rvert + \cos\left( \frac{3\pi}{n} \right)\right] & 2 \sin\left( \frac{\pi}{n} \right) \cos\left( \theta + \frac{\pi}{n} \right) \\
2 \sin\left( \theta + \frac{\pi}{n} \right) \left[ \pm \lvert w \rvert + \cos\left( \frac{3\pi}{n} \right)\right] & 2 \sin\left( \frac{\pi}{n} \right) \sin\left( \theta + \frac{\pi}{n} \right)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
p \\
q
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
2 \cos\left( \theta + \frac{\pi}{n} \right) \left[ \pm \lvert w \rvert + \cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{n}\right)\right] \\
2 \sin\left( \theta + \frac{\pi}{n} \right) \left[ \pm \lvert w \rvert + \cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{n}\right)\right] \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
If $\theta = \pi - \pi/n$ or $2\pi - \pi/n$, then the second equation is identically zero; if $\theta = \pi/2 - \pi/n$ or $3\pi/2 - \pi/n$, then the first equation is identically zero; otherwise, we can subtract $\tan\left( \theta + \frac{\pi}{n} \right)$ times the first row from the second row. In each case, we see that the system is consistent and there is one nontrivial equation.

So, every complex number on the line determined by that equation is a valid choice for $A$, and $\lfloor \lvert A \rvert \rfloor$ is not uniquely determined!

Lastly, one can check that the point $1 - 2i\sin\left( \frac{2\pi}{n} \right)$ lies on this degenerate line so there is no contradiction in the given solution. It is only that the problem setter missed some additional solutions in this case.

---

I made a visualization of the solutions in GeoGebra:

- [Non-degenerate case](https://www.geogebra.org/m/t5gkbj5s)
- [Degenerate case](https://www.geogebra.org/m/v8emmqmw)

I give some screenshots below:

> [image: Screenshot of GeoGebra non-degenerate case solution]
>
> [image: Screenshot of GeoGebra degenerate case solution]

Comment: +1 Thank you for such a detailed answer.

Comment: Yes you are probably correct, that must be what the problem setter had in mind. Profuse thanks.

Comment: please check the original solution I have attached. Any thoughts?

Comment: @AryanSonwatikar Interesting! I'm in the process of updating my answer, along with some graphics using GeoGebra. For the moment let me state that I have used the trigonometric formulas incorrectly, so my formula for $z_3 + z_n$ is not correct. However, the basic idea still holds — in particular, the determinant seems to be right. What I find surprising about the "official" solution is that it apparently does not deal with any degenerate case (i.e when det = 0). This makes the solution incomplete, in my opinion. I will update this answer soon and ping you :)

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AryanSonwatikar Glad to be of help! :) Hope the GeoGebra visualizations kinda helped too